# Easiest way to implement Apple Push Notification

Tags: ios6, apple-push-notifications

I want to implement Push notification in my IOS Application. I have referred few links & also sample code but its not working & crashes.

I want to know that what are the things or steps required to implement this & also if the easiest & simplest way to implement this feature.

Any suggestions & hints will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best Simple [Tutorial about apple push notification](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services?dm_switcher=true)

Top reason why push notification not works is

```
 « After configuring push notification for bundleId /App Id, provisioning  
   profiles are not recreated.
```

We need to configure push notification while creating AppID. If added later then you need to create new provisioning profiles.

Comment: down voters please explain, that's what I got solution after 3days of searching..

Answer (score 0):

This is very good tutorial to follow for newbiee like you.

[Push Notification Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

Just go through it.It has all the steps that you have to follow.

Hope this might help.